# Django with Apache and mod_wsgi on Windows 2008 Server

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

I'm experiencing a problem with deploying a site with Apache 2.2, Django 1.5.4, Python 3.3.2 and mod_wsgi 3.4

Here is my train of thought.

After installing an Apache, I put "Hello world" `index.html` in `htdocs` directory to check if I set it up properly. No problem here.

Than I installed Python, Django (`import django` - no errors) and mod_wsgi.
To check on wsgi I did `httpd.exe -e debug` and got this in return:

```
...
[debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module wsgi_module
```

Than I added following to `httpd.conf`:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache2.2/htdocs/my_project/my_site/apache/django.wsgi
<Directory C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache2.2/htdocs/my_project/my_site/apache/>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

At this point I can't start an Apache no more - `The requested operation has failed!`
And now `httpd.exe -e debug` returns `Syntax error on line 496 of C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache2.2/conf/httpd.conf: Invalid option to WSGI alias definition.`

Please, let me know if addition information required.
This is my first experience and your assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you have spaces in path names in the Apache configuration, they must be quoted.

```
WSGIScriptAlias / "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache2.2/htdocs/my_project/my_site/apache/django.wsgi"
<Directory "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache2.2/htdocs/my_project/my_site/apache/">
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>
```